# LaTeX uses Extra ITS Math font, but I can't find it on my computer. Where is it?

Tags: fonts

In the pdf file created by `LaTeX`, I see a symbol font named **Extra ITS Math**, which I can't find on my computer and can't use in other programs such as OrginPro or Python. I have searched for it on the internet and found nowhere to download it. What is this font and where can I get it?

[image]

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\%
\end{document}
```

will give out this:

[image]

I didn't think you will get this results by the codes above. I don't know the reason.

Comment: Can you show a small example that generates this? (It should be sufficient with this character only.) Also, how do you compile? Does the log say something about where the font is picked up?

Comment: It is probably XITS Math which can be found here: https://github.com/aliftype/xits (and it should be part of your TeX installation and stored in the directory fonts/opentype/public/xits).

Comment: @mickep As this is from a very big template, I can't duplicate one with some lines of codes. The all codes is very large, which is exceed the limit of this website.

Comment: @JasperHabicht  There is not a file named `opentype` in the path of `C:\Windows\Fonts`.

Comment: @Y.zeng This font is probably not installed in the system-wide Fonts directory but it should be part of the files directory of your TeX installation. Search your computer for the file name `XITS-Regular.otf`.

Comment: @JasperHabicht  Here: `C:\texlive\2023\texmf-dist\fonts\opentype\public\xits`. Thanks.

Comment: I wonder why the viewer mangles the name into “Extra ITS.” XITS is the name of the font it’s a fork of, STIX, spelled bakwards.

Comment: @Y.zeng Excactly. I did not know which installation you used. Therefore I could not tell you the exact path. But this is what I meant. It is indeed strange that the font is named Extra ITS and not XITS (which is the actual name of the font). What viewer is this? It seems that the viewer somehow changes the font name ...

Comment: @JasperHabicht  I can't understand this way of naming the font either.

Comment: You can make a minimal example with just enough code to produce this character. We don't want or need your entire preamble, for example. Just the class and necessary packages for this one thing.

Comment: @cfr  I have updated it. Hope you can get that character by the contents updated.

Comment: That code won't produce that character in that font, though. Depending on your compiler, it will use Computer or Latin Modern.

Comment: @cfr  But in my computer, it actually produce that character. What is the reason?

Comment: I don't know. But XITS is not used by default by any engine, as far as I know.